# SSIS Deployment Wizard does not include a configuration file or package from a seperate solution

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, ssis

I have two SSIS Solutions

SolutionA

- Contains one "utilities" package that handles all emails named SolutionA_Utilities.dtsx
- Contains one XML Configuration file named SolutionA_XML.dtsConfig

SolutionB

- Contains one "ETL" package named SolutionB_ETL.dtsx
- Uses SolutionA_Utilities.dtsx package to send emails
- Uses SolutionA_XML.dtsConfig to configure variables

I want to use the SSIS Deployment Wizard to create a set of files in ...SolutionB\bin\Deployment that will allow a user to install my SolutionB package and all dependencies on a target server.

When I create the deployment using the SSIS Deployment Wizard this is what I see in the ...SolutionB\bin\Deployment folder:

1. SolutionB.SSISDeploymentManifest
2. SolutionB_ETL.dtsx

The two dependent files from SolutionA are missing:

1. SolutionA_Utilities.dtsx
2. SolutionA_XML.dtsConfig

When I attempt to install on the target server using SolutionB.SSISDeploymentManifest, I see error messages telling me that SolutionA's configuration file and "utilities" package are not found.

Is this type of deployment possible with the SSIS Deployment Wizard?

If not, what is my best deployment option?

I am using SSIS with SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach for deployment was not technically feasible. To achieve the desired effect we simply copy the root SSIS package directory to the Server that runs the SSIS packages.